# Clearing non-empty collection before assigning it with new values

Tags: c#, collections

In my code there is a collection, let say it declared as:

```
List<SomeCustomClass> myCollection;
```

`SomeCustomClass` is a quite large legacy class, with ~50 properties.

The collection gets a list of values (several hundred elements) from the database, like that:

```
myCollection = UnitOfWork.Query<SomeCustomClass>().Where(.....).ToList();
```

My question, does it make sense from the memory conservation point of view, to call

```
myCollection.Clear();
```

for non-empty collection before populating the collection with new values via:

```
myCollection = UnitOfWork.Query<SomeCustomClass>().Where(.....).ToList();
```

Comment: *does it make sense from the memory conservation point of view, to call*  .... No

Comment: @Selvin thank you, Selvin.

Comment: "before populating the collection with new values via" - that's not what you're doing. You're creating a *new* collection with new values, and replacing the reference stored in the variable. At which point, the old collection (and any items it may contain) will presumably be eligible for garbage collection, assuming no other variables retain a reference to it. You're just doing additional wasted work first if you clear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You are not repopulating an existing collection, you are assigning a new one to `myCollection` variable . After assignment of new collection to `myCollection` variable the "old" one  (if there are no other references reachable from [GC roots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#memory-release) to it) will become
available for GC to collect it, and all it's elements (if there is no other references reachable from GC roots to them also).